# Error in Acumatica while working in Debug Mode ?? JSManager.GetBatchMode

Tags: acumatica

I have been working With Acumatica and it runs quite nicely in IIS. However in the Visual Studio Web Express Debug Mode - I am unable to run. Error in JSManager.GetBatchMode ! What are steps to be done to run in Debug !

The Code is as follows.

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.InitializeControlsOnInit();
        this.CheckLastScreenAccess();

```
    if (!this.IsCallback)
    {
        var renderer = JSManager.GetRenderer(this);
        var scriptFiles = new List<string>();
        PXContext.Session.PXSharedScriptFiles[JSManager.SharedScriptFilesKey] = scriptFiles;
        if (JSManager.GetBatchMode())
```

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica installer doesn't make straightforward copy/paste file. I can tell you more, if you copy paste files from one IIS folder and decide to paste in another IIS folder, with another name you'll face issues, which will be hard to understand and explain and/or reproduce. If you remember, Acumatica during installation verifies whether IIS is installed, and without IIS installer will not work. It's not just empty statement. Local IIS is the only one way of working with Acumatica without making your life more complicated.